# Apache not able to restart after Ubuntu OS upgrade

Tags: server, apache2, reboot

Trying to restart apache from terminal using the following command after Ubuntu OS upgrade from 18 to 22:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

When executing that command, I'm getting below error:

`Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

There was no error log

Comment: You mention an upgrade from 18 to 22, which has no *supported* upgrade path so is this a re-install?  Do you mean 18 or 18.04 as the 18 reflects the *snap* only version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server, and thus 22, 20 & 18 all run the same *snap* packages; unlike for example 18.04 & 22.04 which cannot run the same *deb* packages.  Please be specific & clear.

Answer (score 0):

Running the below command fixed the issue

`source /etc/apache2/envvars`

Comment: What makes you think that OP has a problem with environment variables?